# XPath - select and find value of an element dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<welcome>
 <firstAttribute>1</firstAttribute>
 <secondAttribute>2</secondAttribute>
</welcome>
```

I already have this "welcome" declared as a variable '$welcome' in my XSL sheet.

and let's suppose '$theName' is the variable containing the name, with value "firstAttribute".

now I need to find dynamically the value of the "firstAttribute" of this "welcome" element, for example something like:

```
<xsl:when test="$welcome/{$theName}/value>
```

I've tried many things, but I keep failing miserably.
Is there correct way or syntax to help me achieve this?

PS: There is already something in the sheet which does something similar I guess:

```
<xsl:if test="$welcome/@*[name() = $theName]">
```

I suppose this checks if an element of the $welcome has name = $theName, but I want to go a bit further, and find the attribute of $welcome with name $theName, and then find the value of it (1) for example.

Comment: With the given XML sample, the path `/value` makes no sense as it selects elements named `value` and you don't have any of them. `$welcome/@*[name() = $theName]` selects any attribute node where the name of the attribute is equal to the `theName` variable, but you don't have any attributes at all in your sample, only elements.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong jargon. I meant element - not attribute.
So what I am looking for, is to retrieve the value of "firstAttribute" dynamically via the declared variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$welcome/@*[name() = $theName] = 'N'
```

It seems it didn't need any special expression like text() to fetch the value. Comparing it directly with 'N' worked out

Thank for the answers guys!

Comment: Nice. The sample you provided was confusing. It should have been `<welcome firstAttribute="1" secondAttribute="2">...</welcome>`

Comment: In fact, the original "welcome" element was a org.w3c.dom.Element in a java class.
and the attribute "N" was being set from the class via the Element#setAttribute(name,value).
Really sorry. I provided the sample out of my head (seems I didn't understand it quite well - still new with xml, xsl and such stuff). Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$welcome/*[name() = $theName]` to select the element, you can use that expression in any comparison or any value-of.

Answer (score 0):

You have elements but no attributes in your sample code.

I would try something like with XPath :

```
$welcome[./*[name()=$theName]]/$theName/text()
```

Look for an element $welcome which has a child element named $theName. Once we get it, we fetch the value of $theName.

Comment: There's an error - because the variable cannot be used like that expression, like /$theName/. It needs to be escaped somehow I guess.

Also tried $welcome[./*[name()=$theName]]/text() = 'N'" (because I want to compare it if it's = to 'N') but didn't work either